# Kubernetes pod list somehow tied to computer?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, service-principal

I have been using kubernetes (new to it, so I'm sure I made alot of mistakes, or dont understand what I did) and used several tutorials, blogs, etc to install out current environment.

Our backend services are now all insice a kubernetes cluster, using a Azure Cloud Repository for the docker images.

The issue I have is the folowing. I'm leaving the current project, and have to transfer my work to "the new guy". When I do "kubectl get pods" I get a complete list of all the services (docker containers) inside the kubernetes environment.

If "the new guy" does it(on his computer), he gets a empty list, none of my pods are there. (or deployments/services)
He is able to reach all repositories I created in the cluster, he however does not see any of the pods I created.

The thing is, if I log into Azure on his computer, the list is empty, and when he logs into Azure using my computer he has the same list I see.

The pods are therefore somehow computer bound? Yet they run in the cloud...

He has the same rights I have on the entire environment (we are both owners of the azure account/subscription).

My guess is this has something to do with the service principle I have on my computer( or at least I think it's somehow on my computer)?

Can someone explain where my train of thoughts goes wrong here? Or even better, tell me how I can get the same list on his computer as we get on mine??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you both get the credentials of the AKS? And do you try to get the pods with the namespace in the command like `kubectl get pods --namespace xxx`? Maybe you can check the current context through the command `kubectl config current-context`.

Comment: I think we have the credentials, we tried the command with the namespace tag but no change.

Comment: How do you get the credentials of the AKS?

Answer (score 1):

If you have done everything correctly regarding his roles [Manage access to Azure resources using RBAC and the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal).

I think he's just missing :
`az aks get-credentials --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster`
Be sure to put correct `resource-group` and `name` with the get-credentials.

After that he can test with `kubectl get all --all-namespaces` to check if all resources across all namespaces are available to him.

Comment: This sounds like something we need to try, I will get back to you with the result.